# How to add HTML into error message

Tags: functions, filters, uploads, media, media-library

php I have a filter for limit max upload file size with custtom message. I want to add link there, but html does not work here. Can you help me someone?

Here is my code

```php
add_filter("wp_handle_upload_prefilter", function ($file) {
  $file_size_limit = 1024; 
  $current_size = $file["size"];
  $current_size = $current_size / 1024;

  if ($current_size > $file_size_limit) {

    $file["error"] = sprintf(
      __("File is too large contact <a href=\"mailto:example@contact.me\">admin</a>."));
  }
  return $file;
});
```

My problem is that I got a plain text instead of html.

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Those error messages sometimes include strings that come from insecure sources, so they're escaped for security reasons. You may not be able to enable HTML there without opening major security holes and exploits. As far as I can see, this happens in javascript on display

Comment: Is there any way how to create my own notice only in this "if ($current_size > $file_size_limit)" case? 
I tried everything, echo. print etc but that does not works..:(

I am able to create custom notice only when I use 
```add_action('admin_notices', function () {…}```

But that show message at load page before upload media.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, what I've seen so far tells me this is a difficult question to figure out. Until then, you should use `contact admin at example@example.com` as a stopgap until a solution is found. The key difference with `admin_notices` is that PHP is what's outputting that markup, whereas on upload it's being returned in JSON for javascript to handle, because uploads happen via AJAX. You may get what you want if you use the simple uploader in the media section of the admin area, rather than the JS uploader in post edit screens etc

Comment: @Silmarion did you ever work out how to add a link?  Have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to add HTML:

```
$link = '<a href="mailto:example@contact.me">admin</a>';
sprintf( __( 'File is too large contact %s.', 'my-textdomain' ), $link );
```

In this case the placeholder "%s" is replaced with the value of the variable "$link".
And that variable is filled before.

Comment: I tried that before but that is same.